# New module from scratch throwing unauthorized requesting Identity user management permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, abp

I'm new to the ABP framework version 7, so I created a fully new module.

So I created a new module inside a new folder in the project called "modules" with the following projects inside:

```
MyModule.Application
MyModule.Application.Contracts
MyModule.Domain
MyModule.Domain.Shared
MyModule.EntityFrameworkCore
MyModule.HttpApi
MyModule.HttpApi.Client
MyModule.Installer
MyModule.Web
```

Well, as per the documentation, I am still running the host and auth projects to run the application; when I access it as an admin, I can visualize and see MyModule successfully. But when I create a new user and try to access MyModule, it throws an error:

> [403] You are not authorized! You are not allowed to perform this
> operation!

So I Log in with the admin account and gave the new user the "User management" permissions, and now I'm able to access MyModule

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm trying to find where is the User management dependency, but I need help finding it. I want all users can access that module with no restrictions. Some ideas where I can find that dependency?

In the module service, I had the identity user dependency as:

```
private readonly IRepository<IdentityUser, Guid> _identityUserRepository;
```

Also the `[Authorize]` method attribute

I removed them to see if that is the problem, but the issue persists.

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful to remove the permissions in your existing module so that all your users can view the area you want? I didn't quite understand that part.

Comment: Yes, but how can I remove the permissions? @onurpicakci

Answer (score 0):

To remove authorizations, you can remove the configurations, if any, on your module page for your project. If you also control it on the UI side, you may need to remove the control there.

To control your permissions (I think you are using full layer solution), there are `YourProjectNamePermissions` and `YourProjectNamePermissionDefinitionProvider` classes in the permissions folder in your `YourProjectName.Application.Contracts` project. You can remove the permissions you do not want to use through these classes.

Apart from what I said, it will help you if you examine the [document](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization).

Comment: I look in the Permissions folder inside the Application.Contracts, but no permissions are set to my new module; how can I remove a nonexisting permission? that's confusing